# FE with Angular and query SQL Server using GRAPHQL (without using REST API)

Tags: sql-server, graphql

Is that possible that with out using REST API I can create a front end in Angular and query a SQL Server database (using a stored procedure) using GraphQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course!  GraphQL is a query language over any type of data.
Even though the most common use case is calling rest from the GraphQL resolver methods, it is just because in most cases REST endpoint are already there and it's easier to use them instead of replacing them.

But most tutorials will show you how to use GraphQL without any call to REST.
Here are a few example tutorials (but there are many more):

- https://tortilla.academy/tutorial/chatty/step/1/
- https://tortilla.academy/tutorial/whatsapp/step/5